# How do I get the URL of the visible tab in Firefox/IE/Chrome?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, winapi

No, this is not a *send me teh codez* request.

I am writing a small utility for my own amusement. In this regard, I need the utility to read the URL from the visible/active tab on any of the three browsers (Firefox, IE, Chrome) that are currently open, and then go off and do something with that URL.

I am assuming I'll need to PInvoke for some of the stuff, may be EnumWindows, or GetForegroundWindow or some such. I've ample experience in Win32 API, but at the moment, I'll need to poke around a bit as it's been a long time since I used to have them for lunch, and used to read SDK documentation as a means of entertainment and amusement.

I am trying to think of ways of retrieving the text from the active browser's active tab's address bar. Any pointers in the right direction will be much appreciated.

Comment: But what will you do if the text in the address bar is not the actual page being displayed?  That is, the user could have typed something in the address bar but not have initiated a fetch.  So the browser could be displaying the yahoo.com home page, but the address bar is showing google.com.

Comment: Yeah, that's a scenario I won't encounter. I am developing this personal utility for a fixed given number of scenarios, so the set if finite.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this [example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q249232/) uses EnumChildWindows, but you may have trouble getting it to work in a UAC-enabled, Low Rights IE world.